# Export with mysqldump not detecting the correct Database name

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean

To dump a database,I'm running this command

```
mysqldump -u doadmin -p your_password -h mysql-test-do-user-4915853-0.db.ondigitalocean.com -P 25060 your_database_name \
> /path/to/database_file.sql
```

After run the command it's showing error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'your_password' when selecting the database
```

Then I tried with this command

```
mysqldump -u user --databases DB_Name -p Pass -h mysql-test-do-user-4915853-0.db.ondigitalocean.com -P 25060  \> database_file.sql
```

It's executed the command and dump all 90 tables and at the end it's showing error

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'DB_Name ' when selecting the database
```

Please let know your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use space after parameter, follow the below command, it should work

```
mysqldump -udoadmin -pyour_password -hmysql-test-do-user-4915853-0.db.ondigitalocean.com -P25060 your_database_name > /path/to/database_file.sql
```